# How to extract the n-th value from the text field with delimitors

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL table I have a text column with value 'Yellow|Green|Blue' and another column with numeric value. This numeric value defines which part of the text column to be extracted. Values in the text column are separated with '|' separator.

For example:
If numeric value is 0, 1st part of the text field should be extracted: Yellow

If numeric value is 1, 2nd part of the text field should be extracted: Green

And so on.

Is there a way how to extract it dynamically ? 
Meaning without using CASE statement like:

```
case when u.UD_2 =0 then 'Yellow' when u.UD_2=1 then 'Green' when u.UD_2=3 then 'Blue' end Kategorie
```

UPDATE: We are using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Rather than coming up with a solution to this problem (e.g. using a string-splitting function - and you can a plethora of questions and answers for this sort of thing by just searching for "sql server string split" on SO), you might be better off normalising the data (i.e. not putting multiple values inside a single field) if this is something you will need to do often.

Comment: Or do the split in a CTE

Comment: What is your server version?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, in the subquery extract each category to separate columns and after it, use a case statement to choose the needed category.

```
select case sep when 0 then x.[0] when 1 then x.[1] when 2 then x.[2] end as Kategorie
from (
select *
    ,LEFT(val, CHARINDEX('|', val) - 1) AS '0'
    ,LEFT(STUFF(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('|', val), LEN(val)), 1, 1, ''), CHARINDEX('|', STUFF(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('|', val), LEN(val)), 1, 1, '')) - 1) AS '1'
    ,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('|', val), LEN(val)), CHARINDEX('|', val) + 1, LEN(val)) AS '2'
from #test
)x
```

Sample data:

```
create table #test 
(
    val nvarchar(500),
    sep int
)
insert into #test values 
('Yellow|Green|Blue', 0),
('Yellow|Green|Blue', 1),
('Yellow|Green|Blue', 2)
```

*Note: this only works if there are exact 3 values separated with* `|`

**UPDATE**

And this is a dynamic way to achieve it, doesn't matter how many categories will be separated:

```
SELECT x.Kategorie 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT node.s.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(500)') AS Kategorie
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sep ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 as rn 
    FROM (
        SELECT sep
            ,CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(val, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Kategorie
        FROM #test
        ) AS s
    CROSS APPLY Kategorie.nodes('/M') AS node(s)
)x
JOIN #test AS t ON t.sep = x.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to split your text data into substrings and get each substring position.

Starting with SQL Server 2016 you may use `STRING_SPLIT()` to split a string, but in your case this is not an option, because this function returns a table with all substrings, but they are not ordered and the order of substrings is not guaranteed.

Again, if you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try to transform the text data into a valid `JSON` array using `REPLACE()` (`'Yellow|Green|Blue'` is transformed into `'["Yellow","Green","Blue"]'`) and after that to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema to retrieve this `JSON` array as table, which has columns `key`, `value` and `type` (`key` column contains the index of the element in the specified array).

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   TextValue nvarchar(max),
   IndexValue int
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (TextValue, IndexValue)
VALUES
   ('Yellow|Green|Blue', 0),
   ('Yellow|Green|Blue', 1)
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT d.TextValue, d.IndexValue, j.[value] AS [Value]
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.TextValue, N'|', N'","'), N'"]')) j
WHERE d.IndexValue = j.[key]
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------
TextValue           IndexValue  Value
---------------------------------------
Yellow|Green|Blue   0           Yellow
Yellow|Green|Blue   1           Green
```